# Define screen size constant in Obj-c

Tags: objective-c, constants

Is there a way I could initialize some constant in a method like `-(void) viewDidLoad` for my screen variables (retina, not retina etc) ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C and Objective-C, constants cannot be assigned at runtime because they are constant. If you are asking how to assign to an instance variable, or make that variable accessible to other classes, please update your question.

Comment: I'm just looking for way to initialize variables and make them not modifiable.

Comment: Make them private to your class, then don't modify them and provide `readonly` properties to access them from calling code.